# Pci ethernet , USB ethernet vs Wired Connection

Tags: usb, ethernet, wired, pci

I would like to know why all of the sudden one of our AIO pc's with Ubuntu 18.04
says it has an usb ethernet and PCI Ethernet connection and all the others only show Wired Connection.

It's just a ethernet cable pluged in and all the devices are the same models and the same os.

When does Ubuntu make a difference in showing you this option in the ethernet options?

Comment: After a recent system update, 'Wired Connection' changed to 'PCI Ethernet Connected', strange why Ubuntu does it